# Exercise 6.1 in Serre's Representations of Finite Groups

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to show that if $p$ divides the order of $G$ then the group algebra $K[G]$ for $K$ a field of characteristic $p$ is not semisimple. Now Serre suggests us to consider the ideal 
$$U = \left\{ \sum_{s \in G} a_s e_s \hspace{1mm} \Bigg| \hspace{1mm} \sum_{s\in G} a_s = 0\right\}$$

of $K[G]$ and show that there is no submodule $K[G]$ - submodule $V$ such that $U \oplus V = K[G]$. Now I sort of have a proof in the case that $G = S_3$ and $K = \Bbb{F}_2$ but can't seem to generalise.

Suppose there were such a $V$ in this case. Then $V$ is one - dimensional spanned by some vector $v \in K[G]$ such that the sum of the coefficients of $u$ is not zero. If that $v$ is say $e_{(1)}$, then by multiplying with all other other basis elements of $\Bbb{F}_2[S_3]$ and taking their sum we will get something in $U$, contradiction.

We now see that the general plan is this: If $v \notin U$ is the sum of a certain number of basis elements not in $U$, we can somehow multiply $v$ by elements in $K[G]$ then take the sum of all these to get something in $U$, contradiction.

How can this be generalised to an aribtrary field of characteristic $p$ and finite group $G$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my shot and the problem. I thought of this solution just before going to bed last night.

Suppose that $p$ divides the order of $G$. Then Cauchy's Theorem says that there is an element $x$ of order $p$. Consider $e_x$. If we can find a submodule $V$ such that $K[G] = U \oplus V$ then we can write

$$e_x = u+v$$

for some $u\in U$ and $v \in V$. We note that $v \neq 0$ because $e_x \notin U$. Then consider the elements

$$\begin{eqnarray*} e_x &=& u + v \\
e_{x^2} &=& e_xu + e_x v \\
&\vdots & \\
e_{x^p} &=& e_{x^{p-1}}u + e_{x^{p-1}}v\end{eqnarray*}$$

and take their sum. We then have

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^p e_{x^i}\right)\left(e_{1} -  u\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{p} e_{x^i}v. $$

However the guys on the left are in $U$ while the sum on the right is in $V$, contradicting $U \cap V = \{0\}$.

Comment: Why is the left side in $U$? Did you suppose $e_x\in U$? If so, $v=0$. In any case, both the left and right side may be $=0$ which isn't a problem. I'm not sure you can go about the proof in that way.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat The left hand side is in $U$ because both terms are. To see this, note that the sum of the coefficients of $\sum_{i=1}^p e_{x^i}$ is $p$ which is zero (since the characteristic of $K$ is $p$) and so by definition of $U$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^p e_{x^i} \in U$. The term $-\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}e_{x^i}u \in U$ because $U$ is a $K[G]$ - submodule and $u \in U$.

Comment: Indeed! I still don't understand why this is enough : why does this violate the intersection being $=\lbrace 0\rbrace$? Also, why shouldn't the sums on the right start at $i=0$?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat For your first query: That is because the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}e_{x^i}v$ is not zero. For your second query, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

We have (just by definition of $U$) an exact sequence of $K[G]$-modules ($G$-reps) given by
$$
0 \to U \to K[G] \stackrel{\text{trace}}{\longrightarrow} K \to 0
$$
where $K$ is the trivial representation. We are trying to show that it does not split. Consider a sum
$$
\sum a_s e_s
$$
on which $G$ acts trivially. Then all the coefficients $a_s$ must be equal. What is the trace of this sum?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The trace of that sum is zero, but how does it help us here? Also how is this enough to show that $K[G]$ is not a direct summand of $U$? Should we not consider general SESs like $0 \to U \to K[G] \to K[G]/U \to 0$ where the map $K[G] \to K[G]/U$ being ***not necessarily*** the trace?

Comment: @BenjaLim I think what Countinghaus is saying is that if we assume our sequence splits, the applying the ``fix functor'' we'd get an exact sequence

$$0\to U^G\to K[G]^G\to K^G\to 0$$

But, by what countinghaus points out $U^G=K[G]^G$ and since $K^G=K$  we'd have the exact sequence

$$0\to K[G]^G\to K[G]^G\to K\to 0$$

Which is ridiculous. Thus, we see that the sequence countinghaus wrote down can't be exact, and thus K is not projective, and thus $K[G]$ is not semisimple. I could be wrong though, so I'd wait for countinghaus's confirmation.

Comment: I agree with this formulation, except that the sequence I wrote down is still exact -- just not after applying the "fix" functor. My way of thinking about it wasn't exactly in this language though-- I was just arguing: "any putative pre-image in $K[G]$ of $1 \in K$ must map to zero, therefore this sequence doesn't split." In answer to BenjaLim's other objection: my definition of semisimple is that any surjection must split, so showing this one doesn't should be enough.

Comment: @countinghaus Also I tried yesterday to show that there exists a left $K[G]$ - module $C$ such that $\text{Ext}^1(K[G]/U,C) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Benjalim: If $K[G]=U\oplus V$ and $U$ is the kernel of the trace map ${\rm tr}:K[G]\to K$, then we must have $V\cong (U\oplus V)/U\cong K[G]/\ker{\rm tr}\cong{\rm img(tr)}\cong K$, i.e. $V=Kv$ is the $K$-span of some $G$-invariant element $v\in K[G]$. But if $v=\sum a_gg$ is $G$-invariant then $a_g$ is constant wrt $g\in G$ hence ${\rm tr}(v)=0$ hence $v\in\ker{\rm tr}=U$ implying $V\le U$, contradicting the putative directness of our decomposition $K[G]=U\oplus V$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another solution to your problem. Consider the element
$$n=\sum_{g\in G} g$$
We notice that $n^2=\vert G\vert n=0$ since the caracteristic of $K$ divides the order of $G$. Furthermore, $n$ commutes with all elements in $G$, and defines a nilpotent $G$-equivariant endomorphism
$$l_n:K[G]\to K[G],x\mapsto nx$$
Our last observation is that $\mathrm{Ker}(l_n)= U$. Indeed, you can convince yourself of the following formula :
$$\forall x\in K[G],~nx=(\sum_{g\in G} x_g)n$$
where $x=\sum_{g\in G}x_g g$. We can now conclude that $U$ is not complemented as a $K[G]$-submodule, because a $G$-invariant complement would provide a $l_n$ stable complement $V$ such that $$K[G]=\mathrm{Ker}(l_n^2)=\mathrm{Ker}(l_n)\oplus V$$ which is impossible.